# R: Performing calculations across similarly named columns in a list

Tags: r

I've been beating my head against a wall on this one all night. I've got multiple data frames, each with the same general column structure. For each data frame, the columns carry a unique "_suffix". There are matching rows across the data frames. Here is an example:

```
cat_list <- c("mpg","spd","wt","price")

car <- c("bmw","mbz","lexus","bmw","mbz","lexus")
src <- c("usa","usa","usa","gb","gb","gb")
mpg_usa <- c(5,11,34,0,0,0)
mpg_gb <- c(0,0,0,44,12,9)
spd_usa <- c(55,13,7,0,0,0)
spd_gb <- c(0,0,0,15,43,67)

df <- data.frame(car, src, mpg_usa, mpg_gb, spd_usa, spd_gb)
```

I'd like to calculate the average for the matched rows based on a list of columns I specify. For example, my list of candidate categories is `cat_list`. The data frame contains `mpg` and `spd`. I'd like to calculate the mean speed and mpg individually for the three car types across GB and the USA.

I've tried a few different version of `melt` with no success. I figured out how to search for my column names using this:

```
avail.cats <- names(df)[grepl(paste(cat_list, collapse = "|"), names(df))]
```

However, that obviously doesn't help me collapse for calculation purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `melt` from the devel version of `data.table`.  We subset the column names that are found in the 'cat_list' using `intersect` after we removing the substring in column names that starts with `_`. We can specify multiple `patterns` in the `measure` argument of `melt` after converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
nm1 <- intersect(sub('_.*', '', names(df)), cat_list)
dM <- melt(setDT(df), measure=patterns(paste0('^', nm1)), value.name=nm1)
```

Using the `melt`ed dataset, we group by 'car' and 'src', specify the columns in 'dM' that are common with 'cat_list'  in `.SDcols` and loop with `lapply` to get the `mean`.

```
dM[,lapply(.SD, mean) , .(car, src), .SDcols= nm1]
#     car src  mpg  spd
#1:   bmw usa  2.5 27.5
#2:   mbz usa  5.5  6.5
#3: lexus usa 17.0  3.5
#4:   bmw  gb 22.0  7.5
#5:   mbz  gb  6.0 21.5
#6: lexus  gb  4.5 33.5
```

NOTE:  Instructions to install the devel version of `data.table` are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Dumb follow-up -- but how do I install the devel version of `data.table`? I have 1.9.4.

Comment: I think this is pretty close. The code does work for the sample data, but I don't think it quite fits my need. In the `melt` statement, 'mpg' and 'spd' are hard-coded in. What I'd like to do is have the function look in the 'cat_list' to find the matching categories (in this case, it should find mpg and spd, but not wt or price). I have a long list of category variables, and they won't all be present at any given time. The fields in the dataset will always be a permutation of (a subset of) 'cat_list' and (all of) 'src'.

Comment: @dra I updated the post based on your comments.